# Can I programmatically append tags to <head> from within body in Castle MonoRails / NVelocity?

Tags: javascript, css, assets, castle-monorail, nvelocity

I've been trying to find a way to programmatically add a link to an external CSS file to the `<head>` tag from markup within the `<body>` tag in Castle MonoRails and NVelocity view engine. Anyone know how this can be done?

I need to resolve this problem as the page I work on can consist of many "widgets", and each widget would optimally acquire additional assets such as JS and CSS, rather than putting the `<link ..>` within the body tag and risk rendering problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solutions posted here are not properly working. A better approach is to add your scripts to httpContext.Current.Items

Using same structure as @jishi:

in your view or your viewcomponent, you would be able to invoke something like this:

```
$Style.Add("/static/style1.css")
```

and in your layout (head-section):

```
$Style.Render()
```

Your helper consists of 2 simple methods using httpcontext to store and retreive the list of files.

```
    public class StyleHelper
{
    public static void Add(string file) {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(file))
            return;

        var obj = HttpContext.Current.Items["AssetFiles"] as List<string>; // get the collection which might be empty
        if (obj == null || obj.Count == 0) {
            IList<string> list = new List<string>();
            list.Add(file.ToLower());
            HttpContext.Current.Items.Add("AssetFiles", list); // adds your first asset to your collection and returns
            return;
        }

        if (obj.Contains(file.ToLower()))
            return; // asset is already added

        // new asset ready to be added to your collection
        obj.Add(file.ToLower());
        HttpContext.Current.Items.Add("AssetFiles", obj);
    }

    public string Render() {
        var obj = HttpContext.Current.Items["AssetFiles"] as List<string>;
        if (obj == null || obj.Count == 0)
            return ""; // you never added anything to the collection. Nothing more to do.

        // not using linq here for the sake of readability:
        string res = string.Empty;
        foreach (var item in obj) {
            res = res + string.Format("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" {0} />", item);
        }
        return res;
    }

}
```

In your controller (preferably base controller) add this:

[Helper( typeof( StyleHelper ), "Style" )]
public class YourController

Comment: Hm, I don't see why you would need to add them to Context.Items. A Helper is transient for the current request, so internal state is good enough. I can see that it might break though if you add the same helper to both the base controller and your specialized controller. So just out of curiosity, why do you consider adding it to Context.Items is better? What am I missing?

Comment: old question this one :) 

I dont really remember why i added it to context.items, but at least there is one huge benifit to it, depending on the design of the rest of application; if you dont know if the you have already called the method previously with the same asset this code makes sure you dont add it multiple times :)

Comment: Holy shit, 7 years later I don't even use NVelocity/Monorail anymore :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about adding it to the layout from a view? Because the view is rendered before the layout, meaning that if you create a Helper that would take care of the rendering of style blocks, that would solve your issue.

Meaning, that in your view or your viewcomponent, you would be able to invoke something like this:

```
$Style.Add("/static/style1.css")
```

and in your layout (head-section):

```
$Style.Render()
```

Here is an example helper (inheriting AbstractHelper is optional):

```
public class StyleHelper : AbstractHelper
{
    private readonly HashedSet<string> sheets = new HashedSet<string>();

    public void Add( string styleSheet )
    {
        Add( styleSheet, "all" );
    }

    public void Add( string styleSheet, string media )
    {
        this.sheets.Add( String.Format( "media=\"{0}\" href=\"{1}\"", media, styleSheet ) );
    }

    public string Render()
    {
        var str = new StringBuilder();

        this.sheets.ToList().ForEach( sheet => str.AppendLine( String.Format( "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" {0} />", sheet ) ) );

        return str.ToString();
    }
}
```

AbstractHelper is part of Castle.Monorail.Framework.Helpers. You do not need to inherit that unless you want to utilize the functionality exposed by that abstract implementation. Then, add it to your controller, either your basecontroller or a specific controller:

```
[Helper( typeof( StyleHelper ), "Style" )]
public class YourController
```

Comment: I'll let you know if we manage to do this :) Currently we need to get it to work both with none assets added, and multiple ("nodes"). We're running MonoRails 2.1, let me know if you know for a fact that it's possible on this version. Thanks!

Comment: Added a simple example for a StyleHelper. I hope it helps!

Comment: @jishi : What is the purpose of the AbstractHelper in your code example?

Comment: @Joakim: Apparently nothing, come to think of it. I extracted the relevant parts from our StyleHelper, which probably utilized some of the functionality exposed by the abstract class. I guess I also assumed that I needed to inherit some interface in order to register it as a helper at the time of writing, which I know now is not necessary. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

### CaptureFor

I found out there's a component that does exactly what I was looking for here.

In the view:

```
#capturefor(capturefortest)
    Default way of printing. Use this for unique variables, such as title.
#end

#blockcomponent(CaptureFor with "id=capturefortest" "append=before")
    This will append before 1.
#end

#blockcomponent(CaptureFor with "id=capturefortest" "append")
    This will append after 1.
#end

#blockcomponent(CaptureFor with "id=capturefortest" "append")
    This will append after 1 and 3.
#end 

#blockcomponent(CaptureFor with "id=capturefortest") 
    Overrides everything defined before this. 
#end
```

#### Layout / MasterPage:

```
$capturefortest
```

#### Escaping #:

When putting #, e.g. in a jQuery ID selector, inside a #blockcomponent(CaptureFor), you'll get an error. This can be avoided by setting some globally available variables in AssetFilter and using ${HASH} to print #. Single quotes and quotes are also nice to have:

```
controllerContext.PropertyBag.Add("HASH", "#");
controllerContext.PropertyBag.Add("Q", '"');
controllerContext.PropertyBag.Add("sq", "'");
```

Now you can safely do:

```
#blockcomponent(CaptureFor with "id=capturefortest" "append=before")
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery('#container').html('Awesomeness!')
    </script>
#end
```

Answer (score -1):

It's possible thanks to Javascript! Here is how I would append style to `<head>`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var cssNode = document.createElement('link');
    cssNode.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
    cssNode.setAttribute('href', 'http://path.to/your/file.css');
    cssNode.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(cssNode);
</script>
```

Comment: JavaScript is one way indeed, but its more optimal getting it done already on the server side.